# I carry a lot of stuff in my backpack. How can I protect my laptop?

Tags: laptop, case

I have a backpack full of heavy stuff, and a laptop that I don't want to break. I have noticed an outline of the keyboard on the screen, so it's clear I have too much weight in the wrong places. There are several scenarios that might break the laptop and/or it's screen:

1. Bending over while wearing the backpack.
2. Setting the backpack down, and then it falling over.
3. The weight pushing in the bottom side (as it sits in the backpack) of the laptop when I am carrying it.

The specifics of the laptop and bag are not substantially important, as solutions should be generic to apply to many different kinds of laptops and backpacks, and also to withstand the test of time.

The reasoning for lots of heavy stuff in the backpack can vary substantially, and is therefore also not important.  For example, textbooks, auxiliary cables and equipment, bottles of water, tools, etc.

The most obvious answer might be "stop carrying so much stuff".  However, that doesn't help if you've already removed as much stuff as possible from your bag.

I've thought of a few things that would help the situation, with wildly varying costs:

- Buy or build a semi-hard shell sleeve to put around the laptop before putting into the bag.  These shells usually use the zipper as part of their structural support, and are therefore pretty soft.
- Buy a backpack with - or build a rigid compartment into - the backpack.
- Transplant the laptop into a similarly sized Toughbook case.
- Replace the bag with a harder laptop protection compartment

### Requirements

1. Solutions apply(ies) to many different laptops, bags, etc.
2. Holds up to 40 - 50 lbs of weight
3. Weighs less than 3 lbs
4. Affordable: $50 or less

### Nice to haves

1. Low cost: $20 or less
2. Color options, or other customizability
3. Not made in China
4. Extremely lightweight

Comment: I use a a cheap fixable Thinkpad laptop and simply use a basic laptop.  SSD and ram can be installed and uninstalled.  Got in a wreck part it in my back up computer.  Back up and running with in 10 minutes.

Comment: I'm have closed this question as off-topic because it is not asking for a recommendation of a computerized device. Accessories are off-topic.

Comment: If accessories are off topic, how is there a "case" tag?  By definition, all cases are accessories and 99% of them are non-electronic.

Answer (score 0):

I've had [this](https://www.insight.com/en_US/buy/product/43R2482/LENOVO/43R2482/Lenovo-ThinkPad-Business-Backpack--notebook-carrying-backpack/) backpack a while ago and I think it has a special compartment for a laptop which is made out of a protective material. It has many more compartments, only bad thing is that the biggest laptop it can fit in it is 15.6". I've carried 25ibs in it with no problem, though I've never tried carrying 50ibs. It is a bit over your budget(60$ on the official page) but you can probably find it for less on Amazon or sites like that.